# How to store info regarding which notifications have been read by user?

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child

I have a set of notification or information items stored in elasticsearch. Once a  user has seen a notification I need to mark it as seen by that user. A user can filter documents by read/unread status. Notifications will be viewed by lot of users and seen status will constantly get updated. What is the best way to store this data. Shall I store the list of users which have seen that notification in same document itself or shall I create parent child relationship.

Answer (score 1):

For sure you should avoid parent-child or nested type because they are computationial costful. the best way to achieve the relationship with a lot of data is to denormalize your data and put them in different indices. Please read [here](https://medium.com/wolox/why-and-how-denormalize-indexing-with-elasticsearch-rails-6c3c12f03c7c) and [here](https://blog.vvcephei.org/polloi-denorm) .Example:

```
PUT notification
{"mappings": {
    "properties": {
          "content": {
               "type": "text"},
           "id_notification":{
                "type":"keyword" }{
                   }}
}
}
```

Then user index:

```
PUT user
{"mappings": {
    "properties": {
          "general_information": {
               "type": "text"},
           "id_user":{
                "type":"keyword" }{
                   }}
}
}
```

another index for the relationship:

```
 PUT seen
{"mappings": {
    "properties": {
          "seen": {
               "notification_id":{
               "type": "keyword",
                "fields":{
                   "user_id":{
                "type":"keyword"}}},
           "unseen":{
               "notification_id":{
               "type": "keyword",
                "fields":{
                   "user_id":{
                "type":"keyword"}}}}
}
}
```

Sorry for the text format, i haven't kibana now. You should pay attention that to pass from information indices - user, notification - to the support index - seen - you should make a multi-index query - doc [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-index.html). it will works because the name and the values of the fields - user_id , notification_id - are the same in different indices. The subfields user_id in seen index are array of keywords. However you could make user_id a single keyword and parent of notification_id keyword array field. In every case they keep the one to many realtionship, the best choice depends from your data